# Input named function arguments as one named lists in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to input named function arguments as one named list instead of specifying them individually when using the function.

Let's say I have this:

```py
import numpy as np

class Something:

    __init__(self, one = None, two = None, three = None, **kwargs):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
        self.three = three

    def sum(self):
        np.sum(self.one, self.two, self.three)
```

Right now, I have to do something like this:

```py
Instance = Something(one = 1, two = 2, three = 3)
Instance.sum()
```

But what I want to do is something like this:

```py
Inputs = {'one' : 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
Instance = Something(Inputs)
Instance.sum()
```

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: `Something(**Inputs)`? And that's a _dictionary_, not a "named list".

Comment: You would also have to add a `def` to your contractor.

Comment: Wow, @jonrsharpe, that was quick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `**` to expand a *dictionary* into your function args.

```
>>> def foo(bar, baz): return bar + baz
...
>>> foo(baz=1, bar=2)
3
>>> foo(**{'baz':1, 'bar':2})
3
```